# wiki txt converting to markdown with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm converting some old wiki text in .txt format to Markdown (.md)

I have some javascript examples in the txt text and would like to wrapp them properly so I used: `/(<code javascript\>([\s\S]*)<\/code\>)/` to match those parts.

This regex still missed some parts. Here is a example of the problem:

````
var text = 'This is a text to test:<code javascript>var x = {foo: bar}; alert(JSON.stringify(x));</code>Then any string would inherit that function:<code javascript>"hey howdy!".alert();</code>End of test';

text = text.replace(/(<code javascript\>([\s\S]*)<\/code\>)/, function(string, submatch1, submatch2){
console.log(submatch2);
    return '```js' + submatch2 + '```';
});
````

This logs still som `</code>` inside it.

```
var x = {foo: bar}; alert(JSON.stringify(x));</code>Then any string would inherit that function:<code javascript>"hey howdy!".alert();
```

What am I missing?

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dubLs4ek/

Comment: Read this page: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were doing a greedy search, which will match the last occurrence of the next symbol. You can just a put a `?` after the `*` to make it a lazy search, meaning it will stop when it sees the fist `<\/code\>`

`/(<code javascript\>([\s\S]*?)<\/code\>)/`

Update: To match all occurences

`/(<code javascript\>([\s\S]*?)<\/code\>)/g`

Example: http://regex101.com/r/sT9vD1/3

Comment: Maybe because it does not solve the problem of replacing all occurencies instead of only the first one.

Comment: May be someone wasn't satisfied with the answer. I did miss out the `g` modifier part though. If you wanna match all of them, append `g` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Two errors have to be solved:

1) avoid greedy search by adding `?`

2) replace all occurencies by adding `g`

```
/(<code javascript\>([\s\S]*?)<\/code\>)/g
```

See working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dubLs4ek/1/